# Is there a way to create a "negative image / negative geometry" of an object / curve using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

Is there a way to create a "negative image / negative geometry" of an object / curve using geometry nodes?

**I know I can do it manually by deleting and joining edges but I'm trying to do it using geometry nodes to make it procedural since I want to try out several different variations for 3D printing.**

I was thinking a boolean difference but that still would require some cleanup.

**Example**: I have the **original image** below.

[image: img1]

**But I want the "negative image / negative geometry" of it. see below**

[image: img2]

Node group / Blend file below.

[image: node img]

[image]

Comment: Do you want a "general" solution for negative geometry (a GN solution instead of boolean modifier/boolean mesh node) or "just" for your special case with this geometry?

Comment: A "general" solution with GN would be best, that way everyone can benefit from understanding the concepts.  Hopefully I can take the "general" concept and make it fit my needs.

Comment: Can we assume that it is planar object, of no thickness ?

Comment: "General" would involve to know how you want the negative image to be obtained I guess... because if you want to generalize for more complex geometry, it would depend on if you want a "shortest" path where the "entry" in the original geometry is, or restore the perceived boundary of the geometry, because the human mind can sometimes imagine a shape even when there are gaps in it... so I mean like these examples: [negative image method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEIjm.jpg)

Comment: @StefLAncien yes it is a planar object (no thickness)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann very interesting, for me I would be inclined to use the `"Original Shape (1)"`  But I also see how the shortest path would have it's uses.

Comment: @RickT Not only does it have its uses, the problem with the original shape is, in some cases it is obvious how the original shape was, especially for our brain to complement things where nothing is really there. But how should Blender know what the shape could have been or what our brain thinks how it originally looks? That's why I thought depending on which method you want, this can be really tricky to find a general solution. In case of the star you can try to extend the edges until they cross, with the sphere this will already be incorrect.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann with your great explanation I can see that the `shortest path (2)` may be the easiest best route for this question.  The variability literally could be endless (various zig-zag shapes could almost be anywhere).